# Choosing a warehouse when cloning a database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can anyone give me advice on how to choose an appropriate warehouse size when cloning? Unlike bulk inserts, for example, there is no way I know of to measure the progress of cloning as it's ongoing, so it is hard to know when, say, 10 minutes have elapsed, whether the process will finish soon or will take hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning is a metadata based operation. That's why you do not need to specify any virtual warehouse here. Also you cannot increase any warehouse size to speed up the cloning process.

You only can check the query history for further details on your query.